# Python reference row within applymap

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have 2 dataframes

```
>>> x
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  1
2  3  4  1  2
3  4  1  2  3
>>> y
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  0
1  2  3  0  1
2  3  0  1  2
3  0  1  2  3
```

My goal is to map a 4x4 dataframe z based on the following rules:
for each element in z, find an element in x such that
 the row in x matches the row in z
 the column name/value in x matches the value to the identically located cell in y

So for instance, for the [0,0] cell in z, the row should be 0, and the column should be 1, since y[0,0]=1. Therefore, z[0,0]=x[0,1]=2.

Similarly, for the [2,2] cell in z, the row should be 2, and the column should be 1, since y[2,2]=1. Therefore, z[2,2]=x[2,1]=4.

I'm able to reference the correct column using the following code:

```
>>> z = y.applymap(lambda row: x.ix[1,row])
>>> z
   1  2  3  4
0  3  4  1  2
1  4  1  2  3
2  1  2  3  4
3  2  3  4  1
```

However I haven't been able to reference the correct row, as you see in the previous example I have the row hardcoded to 1. My question is how can I within the applymap function get the code to reference the same row location as opposed to only the value of the input argument?

Edit: As per the comments below, I am looking for z[i,j]=x[i,y[i,j]]

Comment: What 's your desired output?

Comment: Do you want `z[i,j]=x[i,y[i,j]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Numpy's [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), we can express that `z[i,j]=x[i,y[i,j]]`, like so -

```
pd.DataFrame(x.values[np.arange(y.shape[0])[:,None], y])
```

Sample output -

```
In [47]: pd.DataFrame(x.values[np.arange(y.shape[0])[:,None], y])
Out[47]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  2  3  4  1
1  4  1  2  3
2  2  3  4  1
3  4  1  2  3
```

Comment: @ibav Isn't the correct output `[[2, 3, 4, 1],[4, 1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4, 1],[4, 1, 2, 3]]`?

Comment: @DYZ If we are talking about `z[i,j]=x[i,y[i,j]]`, then advanced-indexing as used in the post should be it.

Comment: @DYZ you are correct, I had only spot checked and it seemed Divikar was correct, but when I run it in excel I get the same result as you.

`2 3 4 1`
`4 1 2 3`
`2 3 4 1`
`4 1 2 3`

Comment: @DYZ Yup, wasn't doing the advanced-indexing properly earlier. Got fooled by the square shape of the array. Thanks! Just fixed it.